# Нетерпимый \ Нестерпимый

Tags: лексика

Нетерпимый — такой, с которым невозможно мириться
Нестерпимый — трудновыносимый. нестерпимая духота, боль, жара, жажда.

Есть ли какое-то объяснение почему именно такие значения у каждого из слов, а не наоборот? *Спасибо!*

Answer (score 3):

Все объяснения в толковом словаре.

НЕТЕРПИМЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -пим, -а, -о.

1. Такой, с которым нельзя мириться; недопустимый. Н. поступок. Н-ое положение. Н. хам. Н-ая сплетница.(Его нельзя терпеть)
2. Такой, который отличается нетерпимостью (2 зн.). Он человек ограниченный и н. Она нетерпима к чужому успеху. К тёще он был нетерпим. < Нетерпимо, нареч.(он не может терпеть)

НЕСТЕРПИМЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -пим, -а, -о.
Такой, что его трудно, невозможно терпеть, перенести; невыносимый. Н-ая боль, обида, скука. Мороз был нестерпим. < Нестерпимо, нареч. Нестерпимость, -и; ж.
(такой, что нельзя стерпеть)

Answer (score 1):

Разница в виде глаголов:

(1)нельзя терпеть подобное проявление негатива (несовершенный вид),

(2) нельзя стерпеть, вынести конкретную ситуацию (совершенный вид, приставка С).

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы не ответили. Да, исходные глаголы представляют видовую пару, но разница в значении причастий не вытекают только из этого очевидного факта. Очень примитивно - нетерпимый - из области моральной, а нетерпимый - физической. Нетерпимое явление и нестерпимая боль. Вот объяснить, как оно так получилось на уровне причинно-следственной связи, этого я и правда не могу, да и вряд ли кто сможет...

Comment: Глагол несовершенного вида может обозначать действие вообще,  а глагол совершенного вида - законченное конкретное действие и переход к другой активности: не стерпел и пошел в теплый дом, или поругался с обидчиком, или решил как-то себя развеселить.

Comment: Согласен с Верой: разница именно в видовой паре глагола.

Comment: А я согласен с Людмилой. А с вами обоими даже словарь не согласен. ))) По значению слов. Правда, объяснить, почему так, Людмила тоже не смогла, но это я предвидел.

Comment: Ну Серж - ладно, ему простительно, но, Vera, Вы-то неужели разницу не чувствуете?!

Comment: Действительно, обычно области применения слов разные, но исключения тоже бывают. Моральная область: Нестерпимая жалость пронзила мое сердце. Тут крылась нестерпимая фальшь. Физическая область: Пять минут посижу ― уже все, боль нетерпимая. Бледное лицо выражало нетерпимое страдание.  Думаю, что различие в применении как раз и задается разными видами глаголов.

Comment: А приведённые примеры-исключения откуда? Нашли в Нацкорпусе?

Comment: Да, в Нацкорпусе.